# Generate a public access file temporary and url to access it

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have several files stored as Blob in an oracle database. I render a list to show the user the files stored, and I want to give to him a link to download every file. So I'm thinking in a function that let me to generate a temporary file from the byte stream stored in the database and a temporary url to let the user download that file. The way in pseudo-code would be something like this:

```
File tempFile = generateTempFileFrom(bytes[]);
String tempUrl = generateTempUrlFromTempFile(tempFile);
```

So I could do;

```
<a href="tempUrl">filename</a>
```

As I said, that's pseudo-code, just want to give you an idea about I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good morning,

You don't need to create any file, just to transform your BLOB into a Byte array and send it back to your web client.

For example, using Spring 4 :
I create a controller on GET /download/{id}.

```
@Controller
public class BlobController {

    @RequestMapping("/download/{id}")
    public HttpEntity<byte[]> download(@PathVariable String id) {

        // JDBC code to retrieve the BLOB column
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT FILENAME, FILETYPE, CONTENT FROM MY TABLE WHERE ID = " + id);
        Blob blob = rs.getBlob("CONTENT");
        String fileName= rs.getString("FILENAME"); // ex. file1
        String fileType= rs.getString("FILETYPE"); // ex. pdf

        // Transform BLOB to Byte array
        int blobLength = (int) blob.length();  
        byte[] document = blob.getBytes(1, blobLength);


        // Set HTTP Header to force the browser to open the download popup
        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        header.setContentType(new MediaType("application", fileType));
        header.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file1 + "." + fileType);
        header.setContentLength(blobLength );

        //release the blob and free up memory. (since JDBC 4.0)
        blob.free();

        return new HttpEntity<byte[]>(document, header);
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to download your file using this HTML code

```
<a href="/download/1">donwload file 1</a>
<a href="/download/2">donwload file 2</a>
```

Hope this is clear.

Good luck !

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't realize that solution! I'm gonna try right now